# ModemManager "couldn't check support for device" "not supported by any plugin"

Tags: server, wireless, 22.04, nokia

I couldn't find any questions with solutions on this site or on Google for the following info message in the syslog

```
Feb  3 21:15:17 XXXXX ModemManager[860]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6': not supported by any plugin
Feb  3 21:15:17 XXXXX ModemManager[860]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0': not supported by any plugin
```

Ubuntu version: "Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"

What I'm trying to do: Switch Linux server (running on Dell Latitude laptop) from Google Nest to Nokia Wifi 6 router (model XS-2426X-A).

I may not be making the correct assumption that it's the support message that is the cause of the internet connectivity issues.  I was able to make the same switch a few days ago on a Ubuntu 20.04 server, Dell Inspiron, running these same steps:

1. Edit the netplan yaml to point to the new router ssid
2. Run sudo netplan try

On the older device that succeeded, the ModemManager info message never showed up.

After running these steps on the server with the newer OS, it is visible in the device list of the Nokia wifi app. I started wondering if it's a firewall issue because of this message in the syslog

```
kernel: [1021318.200175] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=xxxx SRC=xxxxxx DST=xxxxx LEN=112 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=601761 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=1 CODE=3 [SRC=xxxxxx DST=xxxxx LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=254 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=136 CODE=0 ]
```

But then a similar UFW block message showed up in the syslog of the older server after the switch, and it persists today, with the application there running fine and communicating with the internet.

Should I look for plugins to be installed for this Nokia device, or is it something else that's keeping the application on the newer machine from talking to the internet?

Comment: Truncated messages, like "`couldn't check support for `" are of little use. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: I'm not sure that the ModemManager messages are significant - however please add the output of `sudo lshw -class network -businfo` so we can map the bus ids to devices

Comment: Looks like 0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0 is the wireless device      Bus info          Device     Class          Description
=======================================================
pci@0000:02:00.0  wlp2s0     network        Wireless 8265 / 8275
pci@0000:00:1f.6  enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. App is now working while pointed to the new router.  All I did differently was restart the app after changing from old router to new router. Didn't have to restart the app on the test server when I did the change there.